# Python Datastructure Suggestion

Tags: python

i am building a small search engine to search a collection of pdfs. From each pdf i extract a set of tokens and store it in database. I do not want to store duplicate tokens in database, instead i want to store count of each token in the database. Does python has any special datastructure that do not store duplicates but stores the counts of each token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a simple dictionary to store the count like

```
storage = {} # initialize
# ...
if !storage.has_key(token):
  storage[token] = 1
else:
  storage[token] += 1
```

**EDIT**

That said, if you're using Python 3 I'd follow Space_C0wb0y's suggestion to use the `Counter` class ...

Comment: if not storage.hash_key(token)

Comment: I'd use a `collections.defaultdict` and eliminate the `if` statement entirely.

Comment: @nikhil: Why did you accept this solution? It is quite inefficient. I think the only reason to do it this way is if you have a really old Python version.

Comment: You should test for a key using `if token not in storage`.

Answer (score 5):

Python >=2.7 has the [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 3):

The collections package has [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which can be used as a key-value storage with a counter:

```
>>> s = 'mississippi'
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for k in s:
...     d[k] += 1
...
>>> d.items()
[('i', 4), ('p', 2), ('s', 4), ('m', 1)]
```

Just so notice: This is not a databse, it's a pure in memory storage. You would have to save this data somehow!

Answer (score 0):

You could always implement an object for every file, giving it a number of methods, like open and display and etc etc. You could then define `__hash__` and `__eq__` for the object, this would allow you to store items in a set, causing the duplicates to just update a single instance inside the set.

This is just another way of doing something by no means is it the best method.